# Python 2.5 string, modified list, into modified tuple

Tags: python, list

I have a string "hello world' that I made into a list that I need to modify into a tuple.
I have kinda got stuck on the code hoping someone can help me.

```
s1=str("hello world")
L1= list(s1)

print type (L1)
list

print L1(5)
```

Comment: -1; *very* basic question, easily answered if you've gone through the standard tutorial. Besides which, your question is not clear; are you wanting `('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd')` or `('hello', 'world')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s1="hello world"
L1=s1.split(" ")
t1=tuple(L1)
print type(t1)
tuple


print(t1)
('hello', 'world')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found another way also.

```
s1= str("hello world")

L1= list(s1)

print type  (L1)

print L1
```